# paginating arrays javascript by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-pagination

i have two links:

```
<a href="#" id="theone" data-do="1" class="loopit">loop it</a>
<a href="#" id="thetwo"  data-do="2" class="loopit">loop it 2</a>
```

then on click i fire a function that loops an array. it works great when there is one loop but mess up when there are more, in this example two.:

```
var jsonArray = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve"];
var jsonArray2 = ["january","fabruar","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"];
var current_group = 0;
var group_size= 5;
var group_size2= 2;
var theskip;
function cycleArray(thearr,thesize) {
var current_items = thearr.slice(current_group, current_group + thesize);
var skip = current_group += thesize;

console.log(current_items);
console.log(skip);

if(current_group > thearr.length) { 
    console.log("no more");
/* then we stop! no more items, so maybe disable button etc */ 
}
}

$(".loopit").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var theclicked = $(this).attr("data-do");

//alert(theclicked);
if (theclicked == "1") {
    cycleArray(jsonArray,group_size);
}else{
    cycleArray(jsonArray2,group_size2);
}

});
```

so the issue is the skip part. it saves the last one, which is crucial, BUT if i pressed the first link i do get the first 5, but then if i press the second link, i get from the right array two results (great) BUT obviously it start from the fifth, and not the start.

how can i do it?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are keeping track of `current_group` with the same variable for both arrays. So when you click on the first button with size 5 the `current_group` var gets set to 5 and so the next call to cycleArray for `arrayJson2` starts at position 5.

In JavaScript you can treat arrays like objects and assign themm properties so a better solution would be to keep track of `current_group` like this:

```
var jsonArray = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve"];
var jsonArray2 = ["january","fabruar","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"];

// Here initialize them with zero
jsonArray2.current_group = 0;
jsonArray.current_group = 0;

var current_group = 0;
var group_size= 5;
var group_size2= 2;
var theskip;
function cycleArray(thearr,thesize) {
// now you can sefely access the property coresponding the correct array
var current_items = thearr.slice(thearr.current_group, thearr.current_group + thesize);
var skip = thearr.current_group += thesize;

console.log(current_items);
console.log(skip);

if(thearr.current_group > thearr.length) { 
    console.log("no more");
/* then we stop! no more items, so maybe disable button etc */ 
}
}
```

Comment: hi. it now starts with the right place, but on second click it doesn't go though the array, and shows an empty array, even though there are more elements in the arrays.

Comment: in the slice, the current_group didn't used the thearr.